# Most general model from given statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

We know that given a model or parametric probability distribution say $f(\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_k)$, it is possible to estimate the $\theta_{i= 1, 2, ..k}$ from the statistics of the sample.

We can use factorization technique or similar other techniques to estimate sufficient, best, complete, etc. kind of statistics.

Is it possible to ask the reverse question, given the statistics say $S_1, S_2,.. S_p$- what is the most general model that could generate the given statistics.

I asked this question to my Professor and didn't get any pointers from her. Does there exist any textbook or research in this direction.

Comment: As a general rule, you can't expect to go 'backwards'. In certain cases, if you know the _distributions_ of estimates, such as $\bar X$ for $\mu$ and $S^2$ for $\sigma^2,$ then you would be able to guess the distribution of the $X_i.$

Comment: If you knew the sample moments $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k$ for many values of $k$ then you might be able to estimate the moment generating function (or better, the characteristic function) of the population distribution and hence get an approximation to the distribution. But I do not believe this is a practical method.